# Using FormCollection in MVC to bring data from a iCollection property to print in the view as a table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

The model of "Medico" with the "key" and the "iCollection of Atendimentos":

```
public class Medico
{
    //ID
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Atendimentos> ListaAtendimentos = new LinkedList<Atendimentos>();
```

This controller was auto-generated by the Microsoft Visual Studio, using the MVC 5 Entity Framework. The "Medico" controller is where i want to use the FormCollection to take the iCollection data from medico class to the view, so i can form a table.

```
    // POST: Medicos/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id")] Medico medico ,FormCollection ListaAtendimentos)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Medicos.Add(medico);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //TODO??

        return View(medico);
    }
```

And at least the view of "Medico/Create" is like this:

```
@model Clinica.Models.Medico

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <table>
            @if (@Model != null && @Model.ListaAtendimentos != null)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-md-2"></th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">Dia da Semana</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">Hora Inicio Atendimento</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">Hora Fim Atendimento</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">Atende Plano neste dia?</th>
                </tr>

                for (var i = 0; i < Model.ListaAtendimentos.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">@Html.Hidden("Atendimento[" + i + "].AtendimentoId", Model.ListaAtendimentos.ElementAt(i).Id)</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">@Html.RadioButton("Atendimento[" + i + "].AtendeDia", Model.ListaAtendimentos.ElementAt(i).AtendeDia)</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">@Html.Label("Atendimento[" + i + "].DiaSemana", Model.ListaAtendimentos.ElementAt(i).DiaSemana)</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">@Html.EditorForModel("Atendimento[" + i + "].HoraInicio", Model.ListaAtendimentos.ElementAt(i).HoraInicio)</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">@Html.EditorForModel("Atendimento[" + i + "].HoraFim", Model.ListaAtendimentos.ElementAt(i).HoraFim)</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">@Html.RadioButton("Atendimento[" + i + "].AtendePlano", Model.ListaAtendimentos.ElementAt(i).AtendePlano)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </table>
```

}

To reformulate my question, how can I bring the iCollection data from Medico>ListaAtendimentos to my view, and use it to check if its `null` and then use the count to instance all the elements it has?

Comment: where is the get action method. How you are loading the model in it?

Comment: i think it is the "using Clinica.Models;" that load the model to it